# Como muestro un objeto tipo vector

Tags: c#, .net

Como muestro un objeto vector que esta dentro de una clase almacén y este esta dentro de una cola, es decir:

```
Queue<almacen> sucursales = new Queue<almacen>();
empleadoalmacen[] empleado = new empleadoalmacen[1];
empleado[0] = new empleadoalmacen("bernardo", 18, "Quispe", "Masculino", "1523189.CBBA", 78724567);
producto[] producto = new producto[k];
producto[0]= new producto(1,"papita",24,"papa","verdura");
almacen sucursal = new almacen(producto, "SUCURSAL CENTRAL", empleado);
sucursales.Enqueue(sucursal);
```

No puedo mostrarlo intenté convertirlo pero no logro imprimir y me bota el namespace.nombredelaclase.

Lo que hice par intentar mostrarlo:

```
foreach (almacen mostrar in sucursales)                                        
{                                           
    for (int i = 0; i < mostrar.Productos.Length; i++)                                               
       Console.WriteLine(mostrar.Productos[i]);                                       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu **clase Producto** sobrescribe el **método ToString**:

```
public clases Producto
{
    //Constructores
    //Propiedades

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Nombre;
    }
}
```

Y para usarlo según lo que tienes hecho harías:

```
foreach (almacen mostrar in sucursales)                                        
{                                           
    foreach(var p in mostrar.Productos)
    {                                              
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
    }                                       
}
```

De esta forma mostrarías el nombre del producto.

Comment: lo intente y no me muestra el nombre, me muestra lo siguiente System.Func`1[System.String]

Comment: @benjaminlatorreaguilar revisa lo nuevo que puse, ahora trabajo con dos foreach

Comment: si, muchas muchas gracias, ya funciona, estuve todo el dia con ese problema

Comment: @benjaminlatorreaguilar si mi respuesta te fue útil te agradecería que la marcaras como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 1):

En C#, cuando realizas ciertas acciones, como son invocar a `Console.WriteLine` sobre un tipo, o concatenarlo con una cadena (`objeto + "cadena"`), sucede que el compilador invoca a un método definido como `ToString`. Este método está presente en todos los tipos, devuelve una cadena y puede ser sobreescrito.

Esto último es importante para tu caso, pues por defecto `ToString` devuelve la representación de cadena del tipo, es decir, `EspacioDeNombres.NombreDelTipo` y, si deseas que `Console.WriteLine` muestre otra cosa al invocarlo sobre tu tipo, pues tendrás que sobreescribir a `ToString`.

---

A continuación, te dejo un ejemplo de como sobre escribir este método en una hipotética clase `Producto`.

```
public class Producto
{
    public Producto(string nombre)
    {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Nombre; // Lo que devuelvas acá determina lo que muestra Console.WriteLine
    }
}
```

`override` indica que quieres **sobre escribir** el método, que serás vos quien indique qué valor ha de retornar en vez del valor de retorno por defecto.

---

Además, quiero añadir que no necesitas hacer esto:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mostrar.Productos.Length; i++)                                               
       Console.WriteLine(mostrar.Productos[i]);
```

Para mostrar tus productos. En su lugar, puedes hacer uso de [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-8.0#system-string-join(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))), de alguna de estas formas:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", mostrar.Productos));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, mostrar.Productos));
```

Quedando con algo como esto:

```
foreach (almacen mostrar in sucursales)                                        
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, mostrar.Productos));                                                                          
}
```

---

<sup>No tienes que invocar a `ToString` sobre cada `Producto`, pues `Console.WriteLine` lo hace por vos. Solo debes sobre escribirlo e indicar cuál será la representación de cadena de tu tipo.</sup>

Comment: me sale un error en el join la llamada es ambigua entre los metodos o propiedades

Comment: @benjaminlatorreaguilar Esto se debe a que, en alguna parte de tu código, se declara otra función `Join`. Puede provenir, por ejemplo, de `System.Linq`, pero sin ver tu código completo solo puedo suponer. En este caso, la opción con un `for` o `foreach` anidado es la que debes emplear.